# Why do I get an Invalid Form Body as an error when I run this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I have this piece of code however I'm not quite sure why I am getting `(node:4890) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body name: This field is required` as an error. And I'm not quite sure on how to fix this matter.

```
const loggingChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === "katsu-member-logs");
if(!loggingChannel) {
const channelName = "katsu-member-logs";
    message.guild.channels.create(channelName, { parent: katsuCategory.id, topic: "Katsu Member Logs" }).then(c => {
        const allUsers = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "@everyone")
        c.updateOverwrite(allUsers, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false
        })
    });
} else {
    await message.channel.send("Oops, it looks like `katsu-member-logs` channel already exist in this server");
}
```

Comment: Does creating a channel without `-` (dashes ?) in it's name works ?

Comment: @Tenclea it worked for me

Comment: I did not try this, but what about replacing the dashes with spaces ?

Comment: @Tenclea with that, I still get the same error.

Comment: Could the type of dashes you're using be somehow invalid ?